# Disabling stratos multitenancy in WSO2 identity server 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

The default installation of WSO2 IS 5.0.0 includes a web application STRATOS_ROOT and several config files in repository/conf/multitenancy which seem to be related to the old StratosLive stuff (Configuration options like paypal, google analytics, cloud services, https://cloud.wso2.com ...)

My question is: Is it possible to get rid of these files for a simple single tenant installation?
I have deinstalled all stratos features, but CloudCommonServiceComponent still gets activated and loads the *cloud-services-desc.xml* and *multitenancy-packages.xml* configuration files. 
When these files are removed exceptions in wso2carbon.log are thrown.

What is the recommended way to remove/disable the Stratos functionality in a WSO2 product?

Answer (score 0):

> *Adding the following as an answer since the content is too long for a comment.*

This is not something that has been fully tested.
But you can get rid of the mentioned issues and get the server to start up  by doing the following.

1. Start the server and uninstall the following features.

   - Stratos - Common Composite
   - Stratos - Deployment Features
   - Stratos - Throttling Agent
   - Stratos - Usage Agent
2. Stop the server
3. Remove /repository/deployement/server/webapps/STRATOS_ROOT
4. Remove /repository/conf/multitenancy/ folder
5. Remove the following lines from the `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/components/default/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info` file

org.wso2.stratos.identity.dashboard.ui,2.2.1,../plugins/org.wso2.stratos.identity.dashboard.ui_2.2.1.jar,4,true

```
org.wso2.carbon.ui.menu.stratos,2.2.0,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.ui.menu.stratos_2.2.0.jar,4,true


org.wso2.carbon.stratos.landing.page.deployer,2.2.0,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.stratos.landing.page.deployer_2.2.0.jar,4,true


org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common,2.2.0,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common_2.2.0.jar,4,true


org.wso2.carbon.tenant.dispatcher,2.2.0,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.tenant.dispatcher_2.2.0.jar,4,true


org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt,2.2.2,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt_2.2.2.jar,4,true


org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.core,2.2.0,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.core_2.2.0.jar,4,true


org.wso2.carbon.sample.installer,2.2.1,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.sample.installer_2.2.1.jar,4,true
```

6. Restart

Once you do the above the server starts up.

But an error is thrown from the idp.mgt component. 'idp.mgt' component  depends on the stratos common component, which is why you get this error.